# Rust, How to interact with gethostname() std::libc

Tags: c, rust

I'm new to Rust and I'm trying to write the `hostname` utility form a rust backport of core-utils. here more: https://github.com/uutils/coreutils

I have the following program:

```
use std::libc;

extern {
  pub fn gethostname(name: *libc::c_char, size: libc::size_t) -> libc::c_int;
}


fn main() {
  unsafe {
    let len = 34 as uint;
    let mut buf = std::vec::with_capacity(len);
    std::vec::raw::set_len (&mut buf, len as uint);

    gethostname (std::vec::raw::to_ptr(buf), len as u64);
    println(format!("{:?}", buf));

    println(format!("{:?}", len));
    //println(std::str::from_chars(buf));
  }
}
```

I'm trying to print to whatever gethostname copies in the char vector but I'm getting something that doesn't look like a string.

```
~[65i8, 108i8, 97i8, 110i8, 115i8, 45i8, 77i8, 97i8, 99i8, 66i8, 111i8, 111i8, 107i8, 45i8, 80i8, 114i8, 111i8, 46i8, 108i8, 111i8, 99i8, 97i8, 108i8, 0i8, 0i8, 0i8, 0i8, 0i8, 0i8, 0i8, 0i8, 0i8, 0i8, 0i8]
34u
```

What would I need to do in order to:
1. Ensure gethostname() is doing what I think is doing ?
2. Ensure I'm coding it correctly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`buf` is a `~[u8]` and is printed as such (i.e. a vector of arbitrary numbers); [`std::str::from_utf8_owned`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.8/std/str/fn.from_utf8_owned.html) and [`std::str::from_utf8_slice`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.8/std/str/fn.from_utf8_slice.html) will convert a (supposedly) UTF-8 `[u8]` into a `str`. (The latter is called `from_utf8` in master; the 0.8 `from_utf8` is bad and was removed, it does an allocation and copy, while neither of these two do.)

Hence, something like

```
use std::{libc, str, vec};

extern {
  pub fn gethostname(name: *mut libc::c_char, size: libc::size_t) -> libc::c_int;
}


fn main() {
    let len = 34u;
    let mut buf = std::vec::from_elem(len, 0u8);

    let err = unsafe {gethostname (vec::raw::to_mut_ptr(buf) as *mut i8, len as u64)};
    if err != 0 { println("oops, gethostname failed"); return; }

    // find the first 0 byte (i.e. just after the data that gethostname wrote)
    let actual_len = buf.iter().position(|byte| *byte == 0).unwrap_or(len);

    // trim the hostname to the actual data written
    println(str::from_utf8_slice(buf.slice_to(actual_len)));
}
```

will print the hostname.

Docs:

- [`Iterator.position`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.8/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#fn.position)
- [`Option.unwrap_or`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.8/std/option/enum.Option.html#fn.unwrap_or)
- [`[].slice_to`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/vec/trait.ImmutableVector.html#tymethod.slice_to) (master docs because the 0.8 ones don't have any text, the functionality hasn't changed, though.)